# deepin-terminal: The drop-down menu does not disappear when I click with the left mouse button

Tags: 20.04

In the deepin terminal the drop-down menu appears when I click with the right mouse button but it does not disappear when I click with the left mouse button but only by pressing the "Esc" key, why?
I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.3 LTS 64-bit.
If I use Deepin desktop instead of other desktop environments (Gnome Desktop, Cinnamon), the problem doesn't arise.
How to solve the problem regardless of the Desktop environment used?

[image]

Comment: That is probably how it was designed. It may be worthwhile to file an issue. One advantage is that the right-click menu does not close too easily.

Comment: The thing is, if I use deepin desktop instead of other desktop environments, the problem doesn't arise.

Comment: Hi @MarioPalumbo, I am having the same issue in Ubuntu 20.04. I have raised an issue on Github. Were you able to find a workaround for this other that using the "ESC" key?

Comment: Yes, but is ugly

Comment: Can you link your GitHub problem here? So I can follow him.